# Ubuntu 20.04 install freezes on 'Updates and other software'

Tags: partitioning, grub2, system-installation, ssd, freeze

I bought a Lenovo T450, with windows 10 pro already installed, 20BUS X64 Lenovo, Intel i5-5300u CPU, 8gb ram 224gb SSD.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside windows to allow duel boot. I have read through multiple tutorials online but none of them have worked so far. Made space on the SSD, made a bootable USB drive (iso). When I boot up Linux I get ACPI errors that flash on and off. Once it has booted I can try Ubuntu and use apps. Looks like everything is working correctly.

When I try to install, the installation gets to the 'Updates and other software' page and then just spins and spins for hours. I have tried everything On that page,Normal installation, Minimal installation, with and without 'other options' selected. Each time just spins and spine. Until i try and move or close the view. At that point it tells me 'Ubuntu 20.04 installer not responding'

I have seen some other posts about an issue like this, but none of the solutions worked. Mounting and dismounting my windows drive, did not work.

I'm lost right now and don't know what to try so this was my last-ditch effort. I have found logs that might help someone figure out what is going on.

https://0bin.net/paste/Wo3tfRjX4Y2mX50I#Fjk5l6Xgm5-nAfnx+mtfIHqd1dwMhgDYo9IHbEptn41